# Get the mean value of list containing NaNs in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to get the mean value of a list which contains some NaNs. By using:

```
np.mean(mylist)
```

the result as expected gives NaN which is wrong. 
What should i do to get the mean?

Comment: No, it's perfectly correct. What is the average of 10, 99, 1.56, Fish, and 20? There is no answer, it's a non-sense question.

Comment: @gelazari Christopher is right. It's not about you not knowing some method, it's about your claim that the NaN result is wrong. Standard arithmetic operations having a NaN as one of their operands always result to NaN. So the mean (i.e. adding up everything and dividing by the number of things) results to NaN if there are some.

Comment: I don't use numpy, that was totally not non-personal. I'm sorry if it came across that way. I was explaining why `mean` gave you the output that it did. The internet is a mean place sometimes, but you can take me off the list of people who are trying to be that way.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl, I think the misconception here is that `numpy` does not make a clear distinction between `Not a number` and `Not Available`. Missing data are also represented by `NaN` values, which might seem unintuitive and unnatural. In this light this question does make sense :)

Comment: Ok, it makes a bit more sense that way. You can still make the same illustration though: if you ask 6 people to write down a number on a slip of paper, lose one of the slips of paper, and then ask someone the average of the numbers the answer remains "Not Available".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [np.nanmean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) to ignore the NaNs:

```
np.nanmean(mylist)
```

---

For example,

```
In [108]: np.nanmean([np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])
Out[108]: 2.0
```

Comment: thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as i am allowed to. :)

Comment: How do you do this if the NAs are formatted as strings?

Answer (score 0):

This way requires only 'math'

```
temp = 0.0
for i in range(len(your_array)):
    if not math.isnan(your_array[i]):
        temp += your_array[i]
temp /= len(your_array)
print(temp)
```